# Domain lock folder permissions on local folder

Tags: windows, domain, group-policy

I think that my domain have a group policy locking permissions on one of my local Folder. (c:\windows\tasks)
But I need to add some rights on this folder to install sharepoint.
Is there a way (for exemple with local policy) to override this and do what i want on this folder?

It is clear that I am not familiar with group policy :-/...

Comment: Do you have a local administrator account active on the machine?

Comment: As this is a work computer, you need to ask your local IT staff. Especially if you're working with Sharepoint, I'd guess they have methods of installing the software you require. Further, it is not likely that Group Policy is locking that folder. That folder can only be accessed by the SYSTEM and by accounts with Local Administrator permissions, which are also necessary for installing software such as Sharepoint. This once again leads back to your IT department being the best place to get this fixed.

Comment: Yes I have an local administrator, in fact I am a dev and I need to fix a part of our software connected with à SharePoint. So I made a virtual machine specially for that. This is my VM , i just added it to our domain to work easier with my dev environment.